# How to change the date format of a DateTimePicker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

How can I change the date format of a DateTimePicker in vb.net so that the date is shown in the format dd/mm/1990, without any time value? I have tried changing the format to "short", and while this provides the date formatting I require it does not remove the time.

Comment: Please don't put C# codes, I really don't know C# :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set the Format of the DateTimePicker to Custom and then assign the CustomFormat.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Refer to the following link:

http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/schedule-time/15001-datetimepicker-format.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this code it works:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim CustomeDate As String = ("#" & DOE.Value.Date.ToString("d/MM/yyyy") & "#")
    MsgBox(CustomeDate.ToString)

    con.Open()

    dadap = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM QRY_Tran where FORMAT(qry_tran.doe,'d/mm/yyyy') = " & CustomeDate & "", con)

    ds = New System.Data.DataSet
    dadap.Fill(ds)
    Dgview.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    con.Close()
```

Note : if u use `dd` for date representation it will return nothing while selecting 1 to 9 so use `d` for selection

```
'Date time format
'MMM     Three-letter month.
'ddd     Three-letter day of the week.
'd       Day of the month.
'HH      Two-digit hours on 24-hour scale.
'mm      Two-digit minutes.
'yyyy    Four-digit year.
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) contains a full list of the date formats.